Accessing Image on Java backend- fails with 403
I am trying to get a base64 string from this url: https://drd.sh/EXJuR7Xogx3LuU8E/
I can access the image in a browser or postman, but not in Java.
I have tried adding the user agent, and all other HttpHeaders sent by Chrome/Postman. I have also tried cookies and confirmed there’s no auth needed.
I have tried sending the request using Http connection, and Rest Template but neither one works.

You need to first download the certificate from the website and add it to your JRE – since the URL in your question is https.
Exporting the certificate depends on the Web browser you use.
For Google Chrome, open the DevTools window and select the Security tab. Then click on the View Certificate button, then select the Details tab, then click the Export button. Choose the folder where you want to save the certificate.
Use the keytool utility of your JRE to add the certificate you just downloaded. The utility is located in the bin subdirectory of your Java installation. I added the certificate to the cacerts file that is part of the Java installation. For my Java 21 on Windows 10, this file is in jre\lib\security subdirectory. I used the following command:
keytool -import -file path/to/certificate -keystore path/to/cacerts

Note that the default password is changeit.
After adding the certificate, I used the following Java code to download the image:
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpClient.Redirect;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse.BodyHandlers;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class HttpTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            URI uri = new URI("https://drd.sh/EXJuR7Xogx3LuU8E/");
            HttpRequest req = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                                         .uri(uri)
                                         .header("content-type", "image/png")
                                         .build();
            HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder()
                                          .followRedirects(Redirect.ALWAYS)
                                          .build();
            HttpResponse<InputStream> resp = client.send(req, BodyHandlers.ofInputStream());
            System.out.println(resp.statusCode());
            InputStream is = resp.body();
            BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(is);
            Icon ico = new ImageIcon(bi);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JLabel(ico));
            System.exit(0);
        }
        catch (Exception x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

Note that I added followRedirects(Redirect.ALWAYS) because without it, the returned HTTP status was 301 (moved permanently).
Since I use Java 21, here is my module-info.java
(I arbitrarily named my module httpclnt. You can name yours whatever you want.)
module httpclnt {
    requires java.net.http;
    requires java.desktop;
}

Here is the JOptionPane I see when I run the above code.


A better solution is creating a separate keystore with that certificate in it, bundling that keystore with the application, then having the code create an SSLContext from that keystore that can be passed to HttpClient.Builder.sslContext.  Modifying the Java installation won’t help when other people want to run the program.
